# Square ImageView in the center of the screen

Tags: java, android

I would like to position ImageView in the center of the screen and set the width and height of the ImageView to the width of the screen.

I tried this, but the width of the ImageView  is not equal to the width of the screen and ImageView is positioned in the top left corner:

```
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)dpWidth, (int)dpWidth);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

In xml ImageView is in the center of the screen:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: I guess , this. some time this code has run after load the screen . so , It cannot change the layout style.please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java code, setLayoutParams is overriding layout rules (params starting with layout_) you defined in xml. 
You need to add the rules to keep centering the image.
Also LayoutParams will take integer in "pixels" not "dp".

So try this -

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)dpWidth, (int)dpWidth);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Also, you might want to play with scaleType to let image fill the space.
Please check here for the available scaleType.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html